# Find size of rotated rectangle that covers orginal rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, geometry, affinetransform

Hi everyone I have a bounding box of faces from the face detection system in the format `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`.

I want to crop out and align the face my current approach is as follows:
calculate the angle from the eye position then rotate and crop using cv2 warpAffine function.

The problem is the new rotated bounding box is not completely covering the old bounding box, how I can calculate the size of the new bounding box so it completely contains the old one

### Orginal image with the rectangle selected

[image: Orginal image]

### Cropped and rotated image

[image: Aligned image]

### Code doing cropping part

```py
center = (x1 + x2) // 2, (y1 + y2) // 2
d_y = eye_center[1] - mouth_center[1]
d_x = eye_center[0] - mouth_center[0]
angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(d_y, d_x)) + 90
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1)
M[0, 2] += (width * 0.5) - center[0] # width is x2-x1 from face detector
M[1, 2] += (height * 0.5) - center[1] # height is y2-y1 from face detector
res_img = cv2.warpAffine(img, M, (width, height))
```

Comment: geometry? consider the points of the old bbox, rotate the points ([`cv.transform`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga393164aa54bb9169ce0a8cc44e08ff22)), calculate bbox around those points.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz seems that if I use old box with cv.transform it returns the coordinates on the original image correctly but how I can then crop out a rotated rectangle?

Comment: you're asking what size to give `res_img` and that hinges on not using simply `(width, height)` but something larger. with me so far? so, try what I said, make an array of the corner points, put into cv.transform. look at what comes out.

Comment: You can use cv2.boundingRect function on the transformed corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dimensions of larger box are (for `w,h = width, height` of smaller box, rotation angle `Fi`):

```
 H = w * Abs(Sin(Fi)) + h * Abs(Cos(Fi))
 W = w * Abs(Cos(Fi)) + h * Abs(Sin(Fi))
```

Center remains the same, so base corner coordinates are

```
xx = centerx - (W-w)/2
yy = centery - (H-h)/2
```